# Same template across multiple pages in web.py

Tags: python, web.py, pythonanywhere

I am having difficulty understanding how to do a site layout with the same template across multiple pages (PLEASE don't just link me to the 'site layout cookbook' on the Web.Py page. It only uses a template across a single page, which I can do already).

My code is below and it makes sense to me, but I would like to know what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to this, so I'm sure I'm doing something exceptionally stupid.

The error I'm getting is:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> at /vip
'title'
```

main.py

```
#coding=utf-8

import web
urls = (
    '/', 'index',
    '/vip', 'vip'
)

render = web.template.render('templates')

class pagedata:
    def __init__(self, title, description, downloadlink):
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.downloadlink = downloadlink

class index:
    def GET(self):
        pageinfo = pagedata("Demo", "Demo description", "http://www.google.com")
        return render.index(pageinfo)
class vip:
    def GET(self):
        pageinfo = pagedata("Demo2", "Demo description2", "http://www.yahoo.com")
        return render.index(pageinfo)

app = web.application(urls, globals())
application = app.wsgifunc()
```

templates/index.html

```
$def with (pageinfo)

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />    
        <title>$pageinfo.title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>$pageinfo.description</p>
        <p><a href="$pageinfo.downloadlink">$pageinfo.downloadlink</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Lani, PythonAnywhere developer here. Are these the instructions you are following? http://webpy.org/cookbook/layout_template. The most important line seems to be `render = web.template.render('templates/', base='layout')`. That says to create your render object with a base template called `layout.html`

Comment: I also believe that the error you are getting is because the pageinfo object doesn't have a `title` attribute. But I cannot see any mistake in your code that would cause that. If you tell me your PythonAnywhere username I can probably help more.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. I'm still learning web.py, so I didn't have the full understanding of how to build the layout. Thanks for your offer though - I like that you responded so quickly!

Comment: Good work! And don't worry about feeling stupid or anything like that. It's totally normal. Programming is really frustrating at the beginning (and for a long time after that as well...)

Answer (score 0):

I was kind of an idiot. Please close the question.

What I had to do was restructure the code to render a separate template, rather than reusing the index one and then set the 'base' element to my layout template.

Comment: You could edit your original question title and append `[solved]` to it, or accept this answer to your own question :) ? Good job on working it out yourself